# Bootstrap row class not propagating down to components in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a number of controls declared like this.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div>Caption</div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

Trying to refactor my code, I introduced a component to encapsulate this particular behavior.

```
<div class="row">
  <app-textbox [caption]="'Caption'"></app-textbox>
</div>
```

The markup for the component is just a copy of the original code.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<!-- <div style="width:100%;"> -->
<!-- <div class=""> -->
  <div>{{data?.caption}}</div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

The problem arising is with the class *row* seems not to propagate to the component. It spreads to the full width (as it's set to 12 **but** it's not the width of the component holding the class *row* - it's smaller). Analyzing the markup in the console of the browser, I can see that the only difference is that there's a tag for the custom control injected in the structure like this:

> div class="row"
>   -- app-textbox
>   -- -- div class="col-sm-12"
>   -- -- input

while the "old-style" generates this:

> div class="row"
>   -- div class="col-sm-12"
>   -- input

One way to handle it is to set the columns on the component in the main page like this.

```
<div class="row">
  <app-textbox [caption]="'Caption'" class="col-sm-12"></app-input-text>
</div>
```

There are, however, two issues that bother me with it making me feel reluctant to this approach. First one is that the component still gets a (very tiny) extra margin of 15px on each side relative to the enclosing component (all the item have it but the custom *app-textbox* gets it twice, probably due to encapsulation). The other issue is that this kind of defeats the purpose of the encapsulation.

I've tried spreading the width of the components and setting different styles/classes to the input boxes etc. After a few hours, I realize that I'm at a loss.

Is it possible to make the injected tag *app-textbox* spread fully in its parent?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @skiabox Kind of. I rebuilt the whole markup and someone else shoved a bunch of custom styling to it. It looked good on the resolutions I tested. No idea if it's properly resolved, though. I'm not with that project anymore so I can't even reproduce the issue. We probably won't ever know the exact cause, regrettably. May I ask why you wonder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For css to be visible in all your components, add it directly to the `index.html` file, or to `app.component.css`.

For example on the **index.html** as the last head element include:

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

That URL was taken from : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/

(I'm assuming that your Angular2 project was generated with angular-cli and the files follow the standard names)

About the extra margin, try checking `app.component.html`. Maybe there's a container div around it. Also check `index.html` itself

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have added perhaps that the styles are present (I see that the control gets formatting as Bootstrap dictates). And the styles like *col-sm-6* work too **but** the width relates to other component than the one with *row* class on it. It seems to refer to the intermediate tag (*app-textbox*). Any ideas around that?

Comment: aah I see what you mean, that's something else. Maybe try place `class="col-sm-12"` on <app-textbox> itself

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Here is the way I solved it.

Original `app.component.html`:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <app-one></app-one>
   <app-two></app-two>
  </div>
</div>
```

Original `one.component.html`:

```
<div class="col-9">
 <p>One</p>
</div>
```

Original `two.component.html`:

```
<div class="col-3">
 <p>Two</p>
</div>
```

I moved 'col' divs from one and two components to the app component:

New `app.component.html`:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-9">
    <app-one></app-one>
   </div>
   <div class="col-3">
    <app-two></app-two>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

New `one.component.html`:

```
<p>One</p>
```

New `two.component.html`:

```
<p>Two</p>
```